# How to split an array automatically with particular value in that array and get the results separate in php

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array
(
    [id_product] => 17303
    [quantity_stock] => 27
    [quantity_ordered] => 123
    [id_customer] => 43
    [id_category] => 735
  )
Array
(
    [id_product] => 17303
    [quantity_stock] => 27
    [quantity_ordered] => 1212
    [id_customer] => 21
    [id_category] => 734
)
```

In this array i want to get the informations separately based on id_category

Comment: What is expected output

Comment: array_filter() helps you

Comment: 1) What is your exact question ? 2) What is your expected output? 3) Have you tried something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `loop` and a new `array` with `id_category` as index.

```
$new = [];
foreach($your_array as $v) {
   $new[$v['id_category']][] = $v;
}
```

All the info should be grouped according to the `id_category`.